# ARM Assembler Subroutine Pointer

Tags: pointers, assembly, arm, subroutine

I am trying to create code using ARM Assembler, and I need to call a subroutine stored in a register. As far as I know, the way to do this is:

```
Label:
    % some code

LDR r3, =Label
BL r3
```

But when I try to compile that, the following error appears:

```
undefined reference to `r3'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to check the instruction set reference. It would have told you that `bl` only accepts a label. You need to use `blx`.

Comment: That solved it. Thank you!